# More readable Spring @Value parameter

Tags: java, configuration, spring-4

I'm aware of that this topic might be considered as offtopic or convention/opinion based, but I have not found any other place that I could find solution for my problem.

I'm writing and Spring application, fully configured with annotations in Java. I'm loading the properties file with @PropertySource annotation:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("myapp.app")
@PropertySource("app.properties")
public class ApplicationConfig {
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer getPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

Let's assume, that I have app.properties file of following content:

```
property1=someProperty1Value
property2=someProperty2Value
```

I'm loading this value with following code:

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
    @Value("${property1}")
    private String property1Value;

    @Value("${property2}")
    private String property2Value;

    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.println(property1Value);
        System.out.println(property2Value);
    }
}
```

This is working perfectly fine. On the other hand, I find it hard to maintain - if some will think that "property1" is not the best name for a property and would like to rename it, then it will be needed to find all strings "${property1}" and rename it. I tought that I could extract it to the constant class:

```
public final class Properties {
    public static final String PROPERTY_1 = "${property1}";
    public static final String PROPERTY_2 = "${property2}";

    private Properties() {  
    }
}
```

This requires refactoring of the existing bindings to new constant values:

```
@Value(Properties.PROPERTY_1)
private String property1Value;
```

Looks nice, but I do not like the mess in the Properties class, I think it will be better to the constant values without bracelets:

```
public static final String PROPERTY_1 = "property1";
```

Which leads to another refactoring in the MyServiceImpl class:

```
@Value("${" + Properties.PROPERTY_1 + "}")
private String property1Value;
```

But boy, that's really ugly. I thought about extracting constant values to the Enum:

```
public enum Properties {
    PROPERTY_1("property1"), 
    PROPERTY_2("property2");

    private final String key;

    private Properties(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    public String getSpringKey() {
        return "${" + getKey() + "}";
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
@Value(Properties.PROPERTY_1.getSpringKey())
private String property1Value;
```

but then IDE reminded me, that annotation value has to be a constant.

After creating this enum, I thought that I might be over-thinking it, and it should be kept as simple as possible. Currently I came back to the solution with constants in format of

```
public static final String PROPERTY_1 = "${property1}";
```

Finally, I would like to ask you to provide another, nice-looking solution, or some reference links where I could read about some common solution.